# Displaying many images with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a web application where I want to display hundreds of images. I am using NodeJS with the Express Framework. 
How do I send images from server to client?

Edit: If I place all images in the public directory, are they automatically send to the browser if the page is rendered or are GET requests generated in time if those images are needed?

Comment: please show your code, give some details like where you store urls of images and how you update them...

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to use express? Usually, static files are better served using a proper web server (like nginx or apache) along with your node/express application or some kind of cdn. In the client you could configure how your images are requested to avoid loading all of them at the beginning, either only downloading on demand or doing non-blocking requests

Comment: No it is not strictly required but I would like to use it, if it is possible ;)

Comment: Yes, but the images are probably better served by an nginx or apache server (which is usually set along with express, which will serve everything else)